# DTS error when a parameter is added to an Execute SQL Task

Tags: sql-server-2000, dts

I have an Execute SQL Task that is (hopefully) going to receive a global variable called `startDate`, which is set to a Date type. A shortened version of the code looks like this:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME,
        @endDate DATETIME

SET @startDate = ?
SET @endDate = DATEADD(DAY, 6, @startDate)

INSERT INTO destinationTable
SELECT  * 
FROM    sourceTable
WHERE   startDate = @startDate 
AND     endDate = @endDate
```

When I replace the parameter with a date (e.g. '08-01-2012'), the statement parses correctly; however, as soon as the parameter is added back in, the statement errs.

I use DTS *very* rarely, so I'm basing this code entirely on Microsoft's [Using Parameterized Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933469%28v=sql.80%29.aspx). Can anyone enlighten me on how to correctly use a parameter in this situation?

---

**Edit**:
The error detail reads "Syntax error or access violation" which, considering the circumstances, I assume to read as a syntax error due to the addition of the "?".

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: "Syntax error or access violation". Sorry, should have mentioned that.

Comment: That's the actual code you're running, with the "?" in it? How are you intending to pass the value for @startDate in?

Comment: I'm assuming that a correctly parsed statement allows you to specify the variables to be used as parameters. Correct me if I'm wrong, but don't question marks identify parameters in DTS?

Comment: I think I understand you. What you've got above is a T-SQL statement which needs to be comprised of valid T-SQL to be used as an execute task. Some more info please: Do you want the start time to be execution time, or do you intend to let the user choose the start time?

Comment: The user will enter the start date upon execution of the package.

Comment: Does this help @ all? Sorry a bit swamped lately, wish I could help more: http://bisherryli.wordpress.com/2011/03/06/ssis-pass-a-variable-to-a-ole-db-source-in-a-data-flow/

Comment: Well, that's for SSIS, my question was about DTS. I ended up going the long way around and assigned the Execute SQL Task statement equal to a global string variable, which I created and assigned in a VB task. Not exactly the most elegant solution, but it got the job done. I really appreciate your help, though, @EricHiggins.

Comment: I'm not sure that I was any help, but thank you for the kind response. If you'd like to put your solution in as the answer and flag it as answered, this will help other users if they come across the same problem.